# how can i use Function.prototype.call instead of apply?

Tags: javascript, function, internet-explorer-8, function.prototype

I'm trying to use a 'Function.prototype.call'instead of an 'Function.prototype.apply' for use in ie8.

```
function testLog(){
  console.log.apply(console, arguments) // not supported 'apply' ie8
}
testLog(1,2,3) // 1,2,3
```

'Function.prototype.apply' is not supported in ie8,

```
function testLog(){
  // console.log.call(console, ...arguments)  //not supported 'spread operator' ie8

  console.log.call(console, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments));
}
testLog(1,2,3) // [1,2,3]
```

I tried to use 'Function.prototype.call', but I'm having trouble because ie can't support spread operator .

How can I get 1,2,3 instead of [1,2,3] using 'Function.prototype.call'?

---

**additional explanation**

I didn't find console.log not supported in ie8.

but,
console.log is written as an example. I hope the focus should be on 'apply' and 'call'

Also, currently running on ie8, 'call' is enabled and 'apply' is still not available.

[apply] https://caniuse.com/?search=ES%205.1%3A%20generic%20array-like%20object%20as%20arguments

[call] https://caniuse.com/?search=JavaScript%20built-in%3A%20Function%3A%20call

Comment: `apply` should be [supported since IE 5.5](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply#browser_compatibility). `console.log.apply(console, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments));` should work fine. Are you sure it’s not `console.log` you need to worry about? Do you really need to support IE 8?

Comment: I wonder if it's not supported specifically on `console.log` in IE8 though. `console` was very, very weird in IE8 & IE9 (and even a bit in IE10). Edit: Sure enough, it doesn't (not `call` either).

Comment: @SebastianSimon - IE8 was very strange. Although it supports `apply` and `call`, it *doesn't* support them on `console.log` (or probably other host-provided functions). You probably know this, but for lurkers: Host-provided functions don't have to be genuine JavaScript functions, they just have to be callable. Old IE provided callable objects that didn't have full Function features.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As T.J. Crowder was able to test and confirm in his [answer (now deleted)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68889657/4642212) and comments, `console.log` in Internet Explorer 8 doesn’t have the (full) `Function` prototype.

> I’ve just verified that although IE8 supports `Function.prototype.apply` and `call` on JavaScript functions, it **doesn’t** support **either** of them on `console.log`. (`console` is host-provided. Host-provided functions don’t have to be full JavaScript functions, and they were very weird in older versions of IE.)
>
> <sub>— [T.J. Crowder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/157247/t-j-crowder), 2021-08-23 08:43:41 UTC</sub>

This means that calling `.apply` directly on `console.log`, doesn’t work. It is, nonetheless, a function, so it should behave as one, even if it doesn’t expose the methods you expect it to have.

In order to get the desired result you’d expect to get with the expression

```js
console.log.apply(console, arguments);
```

you can call `apply` on `console.log` indirectly, using `Function.prototype.call`:

```js
Function.prototype.apply.call(console.log, console, arguments);
```

This calls the method `apply` with the context `console.log` and provides `console` and `arguments` as arguments, which looks just like `console.log.apply(console, arguments)`.

This also works in modern browsers and, of course, it works with any function that takes an arbitrary amount of arguments, e.g. `Math.max`: `Function.prototype.apply.call(Math.max, Math, arguments)`.

Note that the “array” in `apply` must either be a proper `Array` or an `arguments` object, not any generic array-like object (like `{ 0: 4, 1: 2, length: 2 }`). That is because, as [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply#browser_compatibility) confirms, IE8 doesn’t support a generic array-like object as an `arguments`. [Appendix E](//262.ecma-international.org/5.1/#sec-E) of ECMAScript 5.1 is a bit more specific: in IE8, only `Array`s and `arguments` objects are allowed as the second argument of `apply`.

Comment: I can also confirm that you don't need the `slice` call, since `apply` is happy with `arguments`. Here's a cautious version that tries the modern approach first and then uses fallbacks: https://pastebin.com/BHWRGQTx It works (with the first `try` throwing and the second `try` not throwing) on IE8.